# Redgate SQL Source Control does not show changes done by other authors

Tags: sql, version, author, redgate

I am totally new to Redgate Toolbelt and I might come up with a number of questions on the forum. Anyway, I am using the latest version of SQL source control (Version 5.7.6.6321) and if there are 2 different authors making changes in the same object, while viewing the history for the objects, we are not able to see changes from all authors.

E.g. If user A and B are making changes in the object C. User A can view only the history pertaining to user A and the same goes for user B.

What do I need to do in order to view the full history? User A should be able to view all the changes done by user B and vice versa.

Regards,
Anant

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the [permissions that the users](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SOC5/Permissions) have - mainly VIEW Server State, ALTER TRACE to read the Default Trace, and Alter permissions on TempDB (which is where it stores the information about the users).

More indepth info [here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SOC5/Object+changed+by+Unknown)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).